# Is there a font hierarchy in SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, fonts, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

In our .rdl reports the `Arial MS Unicode` font is used. It's not installed with Windows Server 2019 anymore, as Microsoft stop paying for [it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-word/arial-unicode-ms-font-missing/3d389ec7-dfaa-4002-adfd-5b1491cea8a1/):

> When Microsoft included Arial Unicode MS with earlier versions of
>   Office, Microsoft paid a licensing fee to The Monotype Corporation,
>   which is the copyright holder for the font. Someone at Microsoft
>   decided it was no longer worthwhile to continue paying that fee, so it
>   was removed from the Office package.

The license [cost](https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial-unicode) is pretty high for a single server with few cores:

[image]

So, we decided to use as alternative a new font family - [Google Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) - it's free and support more characters then `Arial MS Unicode`.

The issue is that the fonts for different languages comes in different files and the files are of different types and cannot be unified. Also, as I am understanding there is no need to unify these files as in `PDF` the font is embedded and can increase dramatically the file size.

So, my idea is to install all of the fonts on the machine and let the SQL Server Reporting Services to embedded only the needed ones. So, by default all text with have font `Nato Sans`.

The issue is when a text cannot be visualized by `Nato Sans`, for example some `Punjabi`:

```
ਤੇਜ਼ ਭੂਰੇ ਲੂੰਬੜ ਆਲਸੀ ਕੁੱਤੇ ਨੂੰ ਛੱਡ ਦਿੰਦਾ ਹੈ
```

instead `Nato Sans Gurmukhi`, different font is used - `Raavi`.

I am wondering is there any setting controlling how fonts are selected in case the current one is not installed on the machine or not able to visualize the corresponding text?

Comment: How are the reports being displayed, using HTML, or will they be consumed as something like an Excel Document? I haven't tried, but I wonder if reports displayed in HTML support listing the fonts (like a normal website). I.e. `"Cascadia Code",Consolas,monotype`. For the latter problem (*"not able to visualize the corresponding text"*) how would an SSRS report know if the character has a visual character for that font? It won't. For cases like that, you *need* to ensure you use the correct font in the first place; or use a font that incldues all the characters you need.

Comment: @Larnu The reports generated from SSRS are excel and pdf. The excel is clever - if the font is missing or not able to visualize the text, it uses alternative from the local machine (the one you are opening the file). The PDF text is static - so, if there is no font able to visualize the text (on the server) you got [][][]...[][][] instead. How the SSRS know if the charcter has visual character for the font - I don't know but it seems it know. I just want to understand why it is choosing one font instead of other.